# Does SketchUp C SDK have support .NET CLI?

Tags: c, sdk, sketchup

I'm going to write extension for SketchUp, that will share geometry data between SketchUp and Flux. I have C# SDK that does most of needed functionality. I'm thinking about using SketchUp C SDK for easier C# SDK and SketchUp data transferring, if  C SDK has support .NET CLI. Google says nothing.

And my question:
Does SketchUp C SDK have .NET CLI support?

I'm using:
C# SDK based on .NET 4.0

Supported Sketchup versions:
2014,2015

Answer (score 0):

The SketchUp C SDK does not provide any C# interface wrappers. Nor am I aware of any like it as of current date.